# Matrices identity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let matrix $$
   A=  \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$
and $$f(x)= x^2-4x +7 $$

1) Prove $ f(A) = 0 $

2) By applying the above result again and again show that 
$A^5 +31A + 56I = 0 $ where $I$ is unit matrix. Hence find $A^5$

I have already proven the first part, but I have no clue how to work on second part. Can someone guide me please?

Comment: How did you solve the first part? You could likely use the same technique for part 2. Once you showed that $A^5+31A+52I=0$ it is obvious that $A^5=-31A-52I$.

Comment: @Dave The first part can just be done by plugging it in though

Comment: @Shuri2060 so you just computed $A^2$ and plugged in $A$ into $f(x)$? Well why not do the same with $g(x)=x^5+31x+52$?

Comment: The idea is that if $A^2 = 4A-7I$ then $A^3 = A(4A-7I) = 4A^2 - 7A = 4(4A-7I) - 7A = 9A - 28I$.  Keep multiplying by $A$ and you can compute higher powers of $A$ this way.  Also note that this calculation works regardless of the dimensions of the matrix $A$ and thus avoids explicit matrix multiplication.

Comment: Divide $x^5+31x+52=(x^3+4x^2+9x+8)(x^2-4x+7)-4$.

Comment: @Dave I'm not the asker btw. But if you compute it for the second part that completely misses the point of the 'Hence' in the final part.

Answer (score 3):

You know that $A^2=4A-7\operatorname{Id}$. Therefore,\begin{align*}A^4&=16A^2-56A+49\operatorname{Id}\\&=16(4A-7\operatorname{Id})-56A+49\operatorname{Id}\\&=8A-63\operatorname{Id}.\end{align*}So,\begin{align*}A^5&=8A^2-63A\\&=8(4A-7\operatorname{Id})-63A\\&=-31A-56\operatorname{Id}.\end{align*}Therefore, $A^5+31A+56\operatorname{Id}=0$. And, yes, I am sure that it is $56$ and not $52$.

---

Another way of solving this problem consists in using the fact that$$x^5+31x+56=(x^2-4x+17)(x^3+4x^2+9x+8)\text,$$which can be obtained by polynomial long division.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake in typing the question. Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $det(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^2 -4 \lambda + 7$. This is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Both results now follow directly from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. See here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Hamilton_theorem#n-th_Power_of_matrix

Comment: Not sure how the second one follows directly

Comment: @Shuri2060 Scroll down in the link to the section on powers of the matrix

Comment: I see - although I'd argue that result doesn't follow from Cayley Hamilton (it's just the manipulation of the equation)

Answer (score 0):

The relation $f(A)=0$ is either Cayley-Hamilton or direct computation.

Now consider the long division of $x^5+31x+52$ by $x^2-4x+7$:
$$
x^5+31x+52=(x^2-4x+7)(x^3+4x^2+9x+8)-4
$$
so it's false that $A^5+31A+52I=0$; indeed, substituting and using the fact that $A^2-4A+7I=0$, we get
$$
A^5+31A+52I=-4I
$$
It would be true if $52$ is $56$.